# Why would an Ajax Auto-Complete box stops working after navigating to a different page on the same site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, autocomplete

I am working on a site that has an auto-complete search box. The search box relies on Ajax, Javascript and PHP. The user begins typing into the search box and an ajax request calls a php file which polls a database and returns the possible results. This seems to work fine until the user navigates to a different page on the site and then returns to the search page. Once you return to the search page and try a new search, the auto-complete does nothing. If however you navigate to an outside page (Google for example) and return to the search page it works again.

I am not sure if this has to do with some kind of caching or binding that is taking place or if there is something in the code that I am actually doing wrong.

Relevant code in the search page:

```
<script>
    var tax = document.getElementById("taxonomic");
    var sea = document.getElementById("searchDiv");
    var ctt = "";

function updateSearch(str, field)
{

    str = str.split(",");
    str = str.pop();
    str = str.trim();

    if(field == 1)
    {

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                  document.getElementById("resultsSpecies").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("POST","http://.../UpdateSpecies.php?str="+str,true);

        xmlhttp.send();
    }

    if(document.getElementById('taxonomic').value.length > 0)
    {
        document.getElementById('submitDiv').style.display= 'inline';
        document.getElementById('searchDiv').style.display= 'inline';
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('submitDiv').style.display= 'none';
        document.getElementById('searchDiv').style.display= 'none';
    }
}
</script>

<input name="species" class="form-control" id="taxonomic" placeholder="Taxonomic    Information" onfocus="updateSearch(this.value, 1)" onkeyup="updateSearch(this.value, 1)">
<div id="resultsSpecies" class="results"></div>
```

Relevant code in PHP page (UpdateSpecies.php) called by the Ajax request:

```
<?php
$str=$_REQUEST["str"];
$con=mysqli_connect();
if
    echo ...
else
    echo ....
mysqli_close($con);
```

Any thoughts/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you dont have a javascript error? This would stop any further js execution.

Comment: did you check your JS console for any errors?

Comment: MarcB and Lucho Thanks for the suggestion, I thought it was going to be a PHP problem for some reason. I posted the error and solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there might be a 'onchange' event that does your Ajax call and it only gets added to the DOM in one particular circumstance.

Answer (score 0):

Running with the Javascript console I found the following error:

No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Adding the following line of code to UpdateSpecies.php solved the problem.

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: (your_url));
```

Thanks for the suggestions, I thought it was more likely to be a PHP error than Javascript.